# Pandas, is a date holiday?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe. The dates are with time:

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
import pandas as pd<BR>
df = pd.DataFrame([[6,0,"2016-01-02 01:00:00",0.0],
                   [7,0,"2016-07-04 02:00:00",0.0]])

cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start='2014-01-01', end='2018-12-31')
```

I want to add a new boolean column with True/False if the date is holiday or not.
Tried `df["hd"] = df[2].isin(holidays)`, but it doesn't work because of time digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) for remove times:

```
df[2] = pd.to_datetime(df[2])

df["hd"] = df[2].dt.floor('d').isin(holidays)
#alternative
df["hd"] = df[2].dt.normalize().isin(holidays)

print (df)
   0  1                   2    3     hd
0  6  0 2016-01-02 01:00:00  0.0  False
1  7  0 2016-07-04 02:00:00  0.0   True
```